# Erro ao calcular campos no safari do IOS

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, wordpress

Estou com um problema no desenvolvimento de um pequeno sistema de cálculos onde o usuário precisa colocar um valor em um campo e o sistema trás os resultados de acordo com uma conta em especifico.

Em todos os navegadores para windows em computadores e Android funciona corretamente, porem para o safari no IOS os campos simplesmente não funcionam. Existe alguma imcompatibilidade sistemica quanto a isso?

Segue código:

```
<script>
jQuery('.simularparcela')[0].type = 'button';
jQuery(".simularparcela").click(function() {
var valorparcelas = jQuery(".valorparcela");
var parcelas = jQuery('input[name="meses[]"]:checked');
var valorparcela = valorparcelas[0].value;
var parcela = parcelas[0].value;
      jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type : "POST",
        url: "http://www.mettaconsultoria.com.br/calculoparcela.php",
        data: { valorparcela: valorparcela, parcela: parcela, id: 1 },
        complete: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
          var json = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
          switch(json.code) {
            case 200:
            parcela = parcela.replace(/(d)(?=(ddd)+(?!d))/g, "$1.");
            jQuery('input[name="vlrCredito"]')[0].value = json.Credito;
            jQuery('#td_parcela_consorcio')[0].innerHTML = parcela;
            jQuery('#td_parcela_financiamento')[0].innerHTML = parcela;
            jQuery('#td_credito_consorcio')[0].innerHTML = json.Credito;
            jQuery('#td_credito_financiamento')[0].innerHTML = json.Credito;
            jQuery('#td_vlr_parcela_consorcio')[0].innerHTML = valorparcela;
        jQuery('#td_vlr_parcela_financiamento')[0].innerHTML = json.parcelaFinanciamento;
            jQuery('#td_totais_consorcio')[0].innerHTML = json.ValorSaldoDevedor;
            jQuery('#td_totais_financiamento')[0].innerHTML = json.financiamento;
            jQuery('#td_economia')[0].innerHTML = json.diferenca;
            jQuery('#comple_tabela')[0].hidden = false;
            jQuery('#tabela')[0].hidden = false;
            jQuery('.oculta').css("display","");
            jQuery('.info').css('display','');
            break;
            case 400:
            $(".overlap").hide();
            alert(json.msg);
            break;
          }
        }
      });
});
jQuery('.simular')[0].type = 'button';
jQuery(".simular").click(function() {
var creditos = jQuery(".credito");
var parcelas = jQuery('input[name="meses[]"]:checked');
var credito = creditos[0].value;
var parcela = parcelas[0].value;
      jQuery.ajax({
        dataType: 'json',
        type : "POST",
        url: "http://www.mettaconsultoria.com.br/calculo.php",
        data: { credito: credito, parcela: parcela, id: 1 },
        complete: function(result) {
        console.log(result);
          var json = JSON.parse(result.responseText);
          switch(json.code) {
            case 200:
            credito = credito.replace(/(d)(?=(ddd)+(?!d))/g, "$1.");
            jQuery('input[name="vlrParcela"]')[0].value = json.vlrParcela;
            jQuery('#td_parcela_consorcio')[0].innerHTML = parcela;
            jQuery('#td_parcela_financiamento')[0].innerHTML = parcela;
            jQuery('#td_credito_consorcio')[0].innerHTML = credito;
            jQuery('#td_credito_financiamento')[0].innerHTML = credito;
            jQuery('#td_vlr_parcela_consorcio')[0].innerHTML = json.vlrParcela;
        jQuery('#td_vlr_parcela_financiamento')[0].innerHTML = json.parcelaFinanciamento;
            jQuery('#td_totais_consorcio')[0].innerHTML = json.vlrSaldoDevedor;
            jQuery('#td_totais_financiamento')[0].innerHTML = json.financiamento;
            jQuery('#td_economia')[0].innerHTML = json.diferenca;
            jQuery('#comple_tabela')[0].hidden = false;
            jQuery('#tabela')[0].hidden = false;
            jQuery('.oculta').css("display","");
            jQuery('.info').css('display','');
            break;
            case 400:
            $(".overlap").hide();
            alert(json.msg);
            break;
          }
        }
      });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Não funcionam no sentido de estarem desabilitados ou retornam algum erro especifico? Isso é só no Safari para iOS ou MacOS também? O Safari costuma ter um bug em que não inicia o código em Jquery e nem grava cache, esse problema geralmente é resolvido colocando o codigo todo dentro de `$(function() {})` não é o mais correto mas resolve.

Comment: Então, o problema acontece somente no IOS, seja acessado pelo safari do celular ou pelo google Chrome que fizemos os testes, o erro só acontece no aparelho, em windows funciona normalmente, ele retorna um erro vindo da pagina de requisição Ajax, mais uma mensagem programada por alguém, não é um erro sistêmico.